# convert office files ( word , excel, power point) to pdf on windows azure

Tags: azure

I'm building a web application that the user can upload files.
I want the ability to convert office document when the user upload to pdf.
anyone implemented something like this? or find a product that can do it on azure enviroment?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure is supported by Aspose. If you take a look on their website, there is a guide to convert Microsoft Word documents to PDF in Windows Azure:

[How to Convert Documents in Windows Azure](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Convert+Documents+in+Windows+Azure)

You could assume that most solutions will work in Windows Azure, except the ones using Office Automation which would require Office to be installed on your instances. And installing Office (using VM Role or startup tasks) wouldn't be a good idea anyways: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: +1 for Aspose.NET. -1 to their sample. The use of Response.End can be very disruptive to an ASP.NET application. (See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx)